# Criteria for fixed point of an ODE to be independent of the initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have a system of coupled differential equations:
$$\dot{\bf{x}} = f({\bf{x}})$$
where $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto {\bf{x}}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If ${\bf{x}}^{*}$ is a stability point of the ODE, then $f({\bf{x}}^{*}) = 0$. What this means is that there is an initial condition ${\bf{x}}_{0}$ for which the solution ${\bf{x}}(t)$ attains a fixed point and small changes of this initial condition should not change this behavior.

My question is the following. Is there any criteria to check whether the stability point ${\bf{x}}^{*}$ is *independent* of the initial condition? That is, whatever the choice of ${\bf{x}}_{0}$, the solution ${\bf{x}}(t)$ will always attain the same fixed point?

Comment: It is possibly you misunderstood something. If $f$ is regular enough, no solution that is not already the constant solution at the equilibrium point will reach the equilibrium point. Stability definitions and criteria to check them via the Jacobian of $f$ at $x^*$ should answer your question in general. There might be special cases that are not covered by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definitions, isolated fixed points do not depend on the initial conditions unless, possibly, when the system itself (i.e. $f$) depends on the initial condition.

For instance, the fixed points of $$\dot{x}=x(1-x)(x+1)$$ are $-1$, $0$ and $1$. Those values are independent of the initial conditions. It is true, though, that depending on where the initial condition is located (not at any of the equilibrium points), the trajectory will either converge to $-1$ or $1$ (the $0$ equilibrium point is unstable here). But the equilibrium points, per say, do not depend on the initial condition.

Some other systems, moreover, may have a unique equilibrium point which is globally asymptotically stable (or at least globally attractive), which means that the trajectory will converge to that fixed point regardless the value of the initial condition. This was perhaps what you meant by "independence from the initial condition". In that case, look for global stability properties and the associated results. For instance, in the book by Khalil.

The case of non-isolated fixed points is different. For instance, consider the system

$$\dot{x}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}x.$$

There is a continuum of fixed points for this system which is given by the line
$$U:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_1=x_2\}.$$

It can be shown that for this system, the trajectory starting from the initial condition $x_0=(x_{01},x_{02})$ converges to

$$x(t)=\dfrac{x_{01}+x_{02}}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I meant!

Comment: @IamWill Would you mind sharing what part of what I wrote was exactly what you meant?

Comment: When you said "Some other systems, moreover, may have a unique equilibrium point which is globally asymptotically stable (or at least globally attractive), which means that the trajectory will converge to that fixed point regardless the value of the initial condition." This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, then in this case, this is a property of the equilibrium point. You may look at the concept of basin of attraction of an equilibrium point.